# read post request values HttpHandler

Tags: java, http

I'm writing a little Java app which implements an http service that receives http post commands from a client.

The class I'm using to implement all of this is HttpHandler and HttpServer in the com.sun.net. package.

Now I'm implementing an `handle(HttpExchange exchange)` function which handles the request, and I'm having truble reading the post values received by the request because the only access that I have to these values is via  `HttpExchange.getResponseBody()` which is just an output stream.

I'm looking to parse text post values and uploaded files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have written classes that process multipart requests for my project [Sceye-Fi](http://code.google.com/p/sceye-fi/), an HTTP server that uses the `com.sun.net.httpserver` classes that come with java 6, to receive photo uploads from an [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi) card.

This can help with file uploads (multipart posts).

For a non-multipart post, you would need to do something like this:

```
// determine encoding
Headers reqHeaders = exchange.getRequestHeaders();
String contentType = reqHeaders.getFirst("Content-Type");
String encoding = "ISO-8859-1";
if (contentType != null) {
    Map<String,String> parms = ValueParser.parse(contentType);
    if (parms.containsKey("charset")) {
        encoding = parms.get("charset");
    }
}
// read the query string from the request body
String qry;
InputStream in = exchange.getRequestBody();
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
    for (int n = in.read(buf); n > 0; n = in.read(buf)) {
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
    qry = new String(out.toByteArray(), encoding);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
// parse the query
Map<String,List<String>> parms = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
String defs[] = qry.split("[&]");
for (String def: defs) {
    int ix = def.indexOf('=');
    String name;
    String value;
    if (ix < 0) {
        name = URLDecoder.decode(def, encoding);
        value = "";
    } else {
        name = URLDecoder.decode(def.substring(0, ix), encoding);
        value = URLDecoder.decode(def.substring(ix+1), encoding);
    }
    List<String> list = parms.get(name);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        parms.put(name, list);
    }
    list.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be using [HttpService](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html) from [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpService.html).

There is a Basic HTTP server example in the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html)